# Generating reports in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

I'm building a web api with asp.net core with some CRUD functions. However, I couldn't figure out a way to generate dynamic reports. I was thinking about using the following workflow:

1. The client sends a JSON with the include columns, group columns, and filter columns. Something like:

   ```
   {
       "IncludeColumns":["columnC","columnA", "columnB","count"],
       "GroupColumns": ["columnC"],
       "filters": [{"startDate": <someDate>, "endDate": <someDate>}] 
   }
   ```
2. Entity Framework queries the database and returns a JSON list to the client containing the data formatted according to the query.

What's the proper way to do something like this using EF-Core?

Comment: Have you thought in dynamic objects?

Comment: @H.Herzl I don't see how it can help me with querying. Care to explain?

Comment: With ef core it's difficult to generate dynamic queries because you need to manipulate lamba expressions, in that case it's more simple to create sql statement on the fly and then return a dynamic ienumerable

Comment: It's completely reasonable to use something like `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` to accomplish this. However, designing a reporting engine is probably out of scope for SO.

Comment: What about your report viewer? Do you thank about any special viewer or you want to show it as html?